# Android: Stream online ".TS" format

Tags: android, stream, jwplayer

I want stream online **`.ts`** format

I use `android player` and `jwplayer` API , but not work for `.ts` format

How i can stream this format and programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .m3u8 (HLS)?

Usually there's never a reason to play just one .ts file, because it will probably be only up to 15 seconds long.